# React typescript how to type a hoc

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use typescript in my brand new project
but I've a hard time to type an HOC component

```
const withClass = (Wrapped: Component<any, {}, any>, className: string) => {
  return props => (
    <div className={className}>
      <Wrapped />
    </div>
  );
};
```

It doesn't work with this error

Type error: Argument of type 'typeof App' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Type 'typeof App' is missing the following properties from type 'Component': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.  TS2345

so what's the right way?

Comment: Is your App class inherited from Component?

Comment: Yes, it inherits from Component

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Component<...>` type designates an instance of `React.Component`.

If the intention is to provide a component itself and don't limit a HOC to class components then the right type is `ComponentType`:

```
const withClass = (Wrapped: React.ComponentType<any>, className: string) => { ... }
```

It's also preferable to use specific props type instead of `any`. If props should be passed to wrapped component like it's usually expected from a HOC, [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28938) should be addressed as well:

```
const withClass = <P extends {}>(Wrapped: React.ComponentType<P>, className: string) => {
  return props => (
    <div className={className}>
      <Wrapped {...props as P} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the smart reply but being quite new at ts could you explain me the syntax <P extends {}> before the function?

Comment: That's generic parameter, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html . When not specified on call like `withClass(SomeComponent)`, props of Wrapped will be inferred. This is how props are usually handled. See https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide

Comment: I get an error saying that props is implicitly "any". How can I fix that?

Comment: Disregard my last comment: I changed `props` to `(props: P)` and it worked